# IDE for Corona SDK for Mac

Tags: coronasdk

> I am Just started with Corona SDK and could not find any IDE with proper Corona SDK. Can any one list out the IDE for the Corona SDK for Mac.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The Corona SDK IDE's are
>
> 1. sublime text. [source1](http://www.sublimetext.com/2)
> 2. coronaprojectmanager [source2](http://www.coronaprojectmanager.com)
> 3. Lua Glider [source3](http://www.mydevelopersgames.com/CIDER/)
> 4. ZeroBrane Studio [source4](http://studio.zerobrane.com/)

Answer (score 3):

Lua Glider is the best, Am using it since a year am master in that and can help you in that please ask if want any help.

Answer (score 1):

I would highly recommend sublime text 2 due to the fact that Corona Labs now officially supports it. Plus just yesterday, Corona updated and has this cool snippets that allow sample code to be added via a GUI.

Check it out: http://coronalabs.com/blog/2013/12/11/corona-editor-is-now-1-0/

Answer (score 0):

Check out Visual Studio Code – a free text editor from Microsoft
https://code.visualstudio.com/

1. It runs on OS X
   While the full Visual Studio IDE is a Windows-based tool, Visual Studio Code has a native version for OS X. If you’re comfortable with the IDE in Windows, you’ll feel right at home when working in OS X.
2. It supports Corona SDK
   Code highlighting is part of the standard Visual Studio Code editor, and an optional extension called Corona Tools brings Corona’s documentation to the editor. Installing the extension gives you keyboard shortcuts to either open or search Corona Labs’ documentation. While this is currently a new extension with limited functionality, feel free to reach out to the developer, Tobiah Zarlez, to request additional features.